# Capture key inside rescue block in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I am looking for a simple solution here for the problem statement below:

I have a array of hashes like this:

```
arr = [
  {group_id: 51, product_id: 34345},
  {group_id: 45, product_id: 22133},
  {group_id: 90, product_id: 10045},
  {group_id: 2,  product_id: 15495},
  {group_id: 23, product_id: 25085}
]
```

I am running `BULK INSERT` query based on the unique index of `group_id` and `product_id` like this:

```
GroupProduct.insert_all(arr, unique_by: %i[ group_id product_id ])
```

This insert statement throws error of `ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey` sometimes:

> PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "group_products" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_a3bed1e3ad" DETAIL:  Key (product_id)=(15495) is not present in table "group_products".

So, I would like to perform `insert_all` operation inside `begin-resuce` block such that, if a key `product_id` is not found/present, it will rebuild the array and retry.

Basically, I would like to capture `product_id` inside rescue block

Here's what I would like to accomplish:

```
arr = [
  {group_id: 51, product_id: 34345},
  {group_id: 45, product_id: 22133},
  {group_id: 90, product_id: 10045},
  {group_id: 2,  product_id: 15495},
  {group_id: 23, product_id: 25085}
]

begin
  GroupProduct.insert_all(arr, unique_by: %i[ group_id product_id ])
rescue ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey => e
  arr = arr.reject {|r| r[:product_id] == PRODUCT_ID_I_WOULD_LIKE_TO_CAPTURE}
  retry
end
```

Is there a direct way of getting `product_id` say `e.message.product_id`?

Comment: The id seems to be right there in `e.message`. You could use string splitting or regex matching to extract it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @SergioTulentsev. I was wondering if there is a direct way of fetching `product_id` but if `regex` is the only way then I think the solution I've in mind should work. Here's what I am doing: `nums = e.message.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
begin
  GroupProduct.insert_all(arr, unique_by: %i[ group_id product_id ])
rescue ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey => e
  match_on_product_it = /\APG::ForeignKeyViolation:.+\(product_id\)=\((\d+)\)/.match e.message
  arr = arr.reject {|r| r[:product_id] == match_on_product_it[1].to_i}
  retry
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Am doing similar to obtain `product_id`. `nums = e.message.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)`

Comment: @Puneet Pandey Yes, good solution,  I'm realizing that the rescue clause is specific for ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey so it is enough just to check for digits as you did,  there is no need to build a very specific regex as I proposed.